# Noncontiguous table border

Tags: css, html-table, border

Is there a way to have a noncontiguous table border, more precisely something following the pattern below:

`_ ___ _ ___ _ ___ _`

I looked at the border style value, such as `dotted`, `dashed`, `solid`, etc., but nothing matches what I'm looking for.

**Update**

Razor Page

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    
    @{ DateTime? previousDate = null; }
    
    @foreach (AccountsLibrary.Models.Field field in ViewBag.Fields)
    {
        <tr style="@Helpers.HTMLStyle(field.Date, previousDate)">
            <td>@field.Date.Format()</td>
            <td>@field.Value.Format()</td>
        </tr>
        
        previousDate = (DateTime?)field.Date;
    }
</table>
```

Extension method

```
public static class Helpers
{
    // Add different top row to separate fortnights, months and years
    public static string HTMLStyle(DateTime date, DateTime? previousDate)
    {
        string output = "";

        // Fortnights
        if (previousDate?.Day < 15 && date.Day >= 15)
            output = "...;"; // Still need to think about it a bit (linear-gradient)

        // Months
        if (date.Month > previousDate?.Month)
            output = "border-top: 1px solid ;";

        // Years
        if (date.Year > previousDate?.Year)
            output = "border-top: 2.5px solid ;";

        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it can, `border-image` and/or `linear-gradient` will do. Show your codes HTML/CSS that failed and result expected. It could come up with an efficient aswer. ;)

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/o5hprvfm/) ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this idea. In fact, I generate the HTML from a Razor page (HTML) and has several thousand rows. I'm sure there are ways to improve the display by loading only chunk of rows (or even virtualization, but that will wait for later). I think I with stick with a `table` and no adaptive table (such as flexbox). I'll will update my question with a code excerpt.

Comment: I think that linear gradient will be perfect :-) . Hopefully, I'll find something similar for  WPF `Datagrid`.

Comment: Or [this](https://jsfiddle.net/1utLojcf/) keep in mind the pattern will not scale nicely as the width changes

Comment: Thanks again, but I'm not really satisfied yet. I've just realized that if I alternate the table background color rows `tr:nth-child(odd) td { background-color: lightgray; }`, it hides the contiguous border defined by the background radial- and linear-gradient. So, I believe I can duplicates the style and avoid this issue, but it is really annoying.. Perhaps, something links to CSS specificities (not really sure how it is called)..